# Finding inverse of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, inverse

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a normed linear space such that $T^2=T$. Find the inverse of $\lambda I-T$ for any complex number $\lambda \neq 0,1$.

Now by taking the inspiration from Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ I compute the inverse of $ \lambda I-T$ which is
$\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(I+T\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^n}\right)$. Now this operator exists if $|\lambda|>1$. But what happens for $|\lambda|<1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by your insight, we try the following (using $T^2=T$):

$$\bigg (\lambda I-T \bigg ) \left (\frac{1}{\lambda}I+ \alpha T \right )=I+ \left(\alpha(\lambda -1)-\frac{1}{\lambda} \right )T=I \iff \alpha =\frac{1}{\lambda (\lambda - 1)}.$$

Checking, we confirm by brute force that $(\lambda I - T)^{-1} = \frac {1}{\lambda} \left (I+ \frac{1}{\lambda - 1}T \right )$.  This leads me to suspect, by the way, that you actually wanted the summation from $0$ to $\infty$, not from $1$ to $\infty$.